# Get velocity of instantiated prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies, prefab

I instantiate the Rigidbody "Clone" from my Prefab "Bullet" to shoot them in my project. I want to get the velocity of every bullet (every instantiation) I shoot. In the following my code example:

```
 public GameObject throwstart;
 public Rigidbody Clone;
 public float bulletVelocity { get; set; } = 1;
 ...
 ...
 void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
         {
             Rigidbody Clone2;
             Clone2 = Instantiate(Clone, throwstart.transform.position, throwstart.transform.rotation);
             Clone2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Clone2.transform.forward * bulletVelocity, ForceMode.Impulse);
             Debug.Log("Velocity Clone Instanz: " + Clone2.mass);
             Debug.Log("Velocity Clone Instanz: " + Clone2.velocity);
         }
     }
```

With the code above I get the velocity/mass of my prefab (But velocity is always (0, 0, 0), mass is correct). What am I doing wrong, how is it possible to get the velocity of every instantiated bullet?

Answer (score 0):

Physics are only updated in the next [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) call.

So at this moment the velocity probably simply is still 0.

Instead of a force I would rather simply set

```
Clone2.velocity = bulletVelocity;
```

which is totally fine for initializing bullets as here we explictely **want** an immediate velocity change.

Note btw that `Clone2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` is pretty redundant .. `Clone2` already **is** the `Rigidbody`.

---

If you really want to do what you are currently trying you would probably have to wait until the `FixedUpdate` and do e.g.

```
void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
         var Clone2 = Instantiate(Clone, throwstart.transform.position, throwstart.transform.rotation);
         Clone2.AddForce(Clone2.transform.forward * bulletVelocity, ForceMode.Impulse);
         
         StartCoroutine(ShowVelocity(Clone2));
     }
 }

private IEnumerator ShowVelocity(Rigidbody rigidbody)
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    Debug.Log("Mass Clone Instanz: " + rigidbody.mass);
    Debug.Log("Velocity Clone Instanz: " + rigidbody.velocity);
}
```